# Shorter proof for some equvalences

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group show that

A) $G$ is abelian

B) For all $x,y\in G: (xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$

C) For all $x,y\in G: (xy)^{2}=x^{2}y^{2}$

D) There existst an $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $x,y\in G$

$\displaystyle (xy)^{n-1}=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}$ and $\displaystyle (xy)^{n}=x^{n}y^{n}$ and $\displaystyle (xy)^{n+1}=x^{n+1}y^{n+1}$

are equivalent.

---

I showed $A\iff B,A\iff C$ and $A\iff D$. That was not really hard, except maybe $D\Rightarrow A$. I would like to do a circular argument, but i have no idea how. 
Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For C implies D use n=1.  Then all you need to show is B implies C.  But B implies C seems kind of unnatural...

Answer (score 2):

So you're basically asking how to prove that B)$\implies$C) and C)$\implies$D).

$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #4B0082]{B)\implies C)}$

Note that $$\begin{align} \forall x,y\in G\left((xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}\right) &\implies \forall x,y\in G\left(y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}\right)\\ &\implies \forall x,y\in G\left(xy=yx\right)\\ &\implies \forall x,y\in G\left((xy)^2=x^2y^2\right).\end{align}$$

$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #4B0082]{C)\implies D)}$

As noted by [Seth](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31659/seth) in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729047/shorter-proof-for-some-equvalences#comment1522113_729047), assume C) is true and let $n=1$.

Comment: thank you,but you didn't you just prove that B implies A implies C?

Comment: @PaulH It seems I did. I didn't even notice A). Sorry. In view of this, I think a direct proof of B)$\implies$C) is unlikely.

Comment: no problem, what about B implies A implies C implies D implies B? Do you have an idea how to show D implies B?

Comment: @PaulH You can't, I don't know what I was thinking. Comment removed.

Comment: Ok, but for C => D is it possible. This is starting to confuse me.

Comment: @PaulH D) is an existential statement. One way to prove an existential statement is to pinpoint an element that satisfies what comes after $\exists$. For D)$\implies$B), the existential statement D) is no longer your goal, but it is an hypothesis. There is an $n$ such that... but you don't know what $n$ it is.

Comment: True, now that you explained it that way, i get it. I guess my mind was just blank